# Sending slack message when Pods are inceased or decreased

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, lambda, amazon-eks, slack

I have a question for AWS Lambda with Kubernetes.

I want to get alarms at Slack thorough AWS Lambda and AWS Cloud-watch when amazon eks Pod's are increased or decreased.

I followed sample practice according to the below link and succeed.
[https://antonputra.com/amazon/send-aws-cloudwatch-alarms-to-slack/#create-lambda-function](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

So, I just wonder it's also possible that AWS Lambda can detect increase and decrease of Kubernetes pods.
If it is, could you give me any links or guidence for that?
I appreciate your help.

What I want to do is that I want to get alarms at Slack when pods are increased or decreased on kubernetes through AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Yes, you can do it in multiple ways. If you are running the **Cloud watch** **metrics** and getting a **count** of PODs in the EKS cluster it would be easy to monitor and push messages to the **SNS** topic.

**Option 2**

You can install the Cloud watch daemon set and push logs to the cloud watch match pattern in **event logs** from EKS to delete or create POD. If pattern matches push the SNS message and further processed by Lambda.

**Option 3** (Without SNS, Lambda or Cloudwatch)

Directly run the one POD into the K8s cluster to monitor the namespace if PODs start/delete run send the message on **Slack** webhook.

Ref : https://github.com/harsh4870/Slack-Post-On-POD-Ready-State

You can also use the [Kubewatch](https://github.com/vmware-archive/kubewatch) from VMware